# неизменный суффикс Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

мне надо сделать неизменный суффикс в Edittext, чтобы я вводил денные и этот символ двигался. Как это можно сделать програмно? я использовать библиотеку github, но она не заработала, есть еще какие-то библиотеки или варианты

Comment: Вот тут пишут, что есть суффикс, правда, он двигаться не будет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779635/3212712. Там же есть и варианты кода для префикса. По идее, его можно модифицировать и для реализации суффикса.

Comment: И тут ещё есть что-то похожее на то, что вам нужно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703686/edittext-with-not-editable-not-cancellable-suffix

Answer (score 2):

Используйте атрибут `suffixText` класса `TextInputLayout`.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:suffixText=" your suffix">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```